# How to check database for existing usernames that are not itself before updating using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an list of users that I need to update in the database (using EF6 and SqlServer).  My user entity has an ID (int) and a Username (string).  The ID is the primary key but the username has to be unique as well (I cannot edit the database in any way to solve).

My issue is that I need to be able to check if the developer changed the username to another username that already exists in the database and, if so, throw an exception.

I tried to do it this way:

```
bool includesExistingUsernames = userRepository.SearchFor(u => updateUserModel.Any(uu=> uu.ID != u.ID && uu.Username == u.Username)).Count() > 0;
```

But I get this error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'ServiceContracts.Models.User.UserUpdateModel'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I do this for the Insert, which is easy:

```
List<string> modelUsernames = userInsertModel.Select(u => u.Username).ToList();
bool includesExistingUsernames = userRepository.SearchFor(u => modelUsernames.Contains(u.Username)).Count() > 0;
```

But for the update, I have to check if a username exists that does NOT also have the same ID.  This way it will allow updates to existing users that aren't changing their names but will prevent updates to users if the username is changed to a username that already exists under another ID.

Comment: If at all possible, you should *really* look to solve this on the DB end.  If you try to solve it on the application side you can have race conditions.  For example, two users who both change their names to the same thing at the same time can both end up being rejected.  It also means you need to have multiple round trips to your DB every time you want to change the name, which harms performance pretty noticeably.

Comment: @Servy yes, like I mentioned, I don't have that luxury or I would.